# Pass value from provider to controller in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying get data from db to UI. Url given via provider is getting the data.

**Controller** in controller DetailsProvider.getDashboardDetails() is getting null.

```
var appmod = angular.module('project.DetailDashboardController', []);

appmod.controller("DetailDashboardController", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'DetailsProvider',function($rootScope, $scope, $state,DetailsProvider) {
    console.log("DetailDashboardController --- ");

    $scope.DetList= DetailsProvider.getDashboardDetails()

}]);

})(window, window.angular);
```

**provider** which will call the list

```
(function(angular) {

var appmod = angular.module('project.DetailsServiceProvider', []);  
appmod.provider('DetailsProvider', function() {
    this.$get = ['_$rest', function DetailServiceFactory(_$rest) {
        return new DetailsProvider(_$rest);
    }];
});

function DetailsProvider(_$rest) {
    this._$rest = _$rest,
    this.getDashboardDetails = function(_callback, _data) {
        var newData = null;
        _$rest.post({
            url: window.localStorage.getItem('contextPath') +'home/listdetail',
            data: {} ,
            onSuccess:_callback
            }
        });

    }
};

})(window.angular);
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of reply!

Comment: what exactly i want to know is how a function's success value (function in constructor) can pass to the controller? one thing to notice is that the call is in the provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `promise` from your service method and do `then`able in your controller.

**Root Cause :** your are returning the `newData` which will initalized later after completing the ajax call.Before completing it,you are returning the same variable which will be always null.

In provider,

```
(function(angular) {

var appmod = angular.module('project.DetailsServiceProvider', []);  
appmod.provider('DetailsProvider', function() {
    this.$get = ['_$rest', function DetailServiceFactory(_$rest) {
        return new DetailsProvider(_$rest);
    }];
});

function DetailsProvider(_$rest) {
    this._$rest = _$rest,
    this.getDashboardDetails = function(_callback, _data) {
        var newData = null;
        _$rest.post({
            url: window.localStorage.getItem('contextPath') +'home/listdetail',
            data: {} ,
            onSuccess:_callback
            }
        });         
    }
};

})(window.angular);
```

and in controller,

```
$scope.list = function() {
    DetailsService.getDashboardDetails(function(data){

            varr holdIt = data.data.DList;

        });
};
```

Comment: DetailsService is a provider for me.. _$rest  is defined one. should pass as mentioned above.. now i changed the name pls do check with that

Comment: u making the things very complicated.Why u need provider.Just u use Service API.Please check the edit

Comment: This is the structure have to follow.. i can't change  the thing.. and badly stuck.. and i'm new to this . constructor provider and the controller these all are required